# Determining the right position in minimax tic-tac-toe

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I tried to code a simple version of tic-tac-toe in C++ using the minimax algorithm but ran into a problem while trying to determine the position where the score is the best. The minEval (Returns score for min), maxEval(returns score for max) and playMove (determines which position to play and then plays the move) functions are shown below.

```
int maxEval(int board[9]) {
    if (checkDraw(board)) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (checkWin(board)) {
        return -1000;
    }
    int finalScore = -1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (board[i] == 0) {
            board[i] = 1;
            int score = minEval(board);
            if (score > finalScore) {
                finalScore = score;
            }
            board[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return finalScore;
}

int minEval(int board[9]) {
    if (checkDraw(board)) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (checkWin(board)) {
        return 1000;
    }
    int finalScore = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (board[i] == 0) {
            board[i] = -1;
            int score = maxEval(board);
            if (score < finalScore) {
                finalScore = score;
            }
            board[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return finalScore;
}

void playMove(int board[9], int player) {
    int finalScore = player * -1000;
    int position;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (board[i] == 0) {
            board[i] = player;
            int score;
            if (player == 1) {
                score = maxEval(board);
            }
            else {
                score = minEval(board);
            }
            if (player == 1 && score >= finalScore) {
                finalScore = score;
                position = i;
            }
            else if (player == -1 && score <= finalScore) {
                finalScore = score;
                position = i;
            }
            board[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    board[position] = player;
}
```

When I tested different positions to see whether minEval and maxEval correctly evaluate the position, the functions return the correct score (1000 for max win, -1000 for min win and 0 for a draw). However, when I make the AI play by using the playMove function, it plays very dubious moves and almost always makes "incorrect" moves. 
Here is an example of a game I made the program play (with itself):

[image: A game with itself by repeatedly calling the playMove function in a loop]

I suspect that there is something wrong with the way I set position to i, but I tried to make changes to no avail. Any suggestions as to what is wrong with the evaluate function? Thanks.

Here is the link to the entire code: http://ideone.com/6791d4

Comment: your code has compilation error as of now, please correct it

Comment: I had a header file on my computer, so I forgot to add definitions at the top, sorry about that. I fixed it now, thanks for your input.

Comment: I have a few suggestions:

Comment: @RichardSt-Cyr I'd love to hear them!

Comment: Sorry about that. Pressed enter too soon.

I have a few suggestions:

In minEval and maxEval, you should evaluate if you have a winner before you check for a draw. If the 9th move is the winning move, you will declare a draw before checking if it's a win.

In evaluate, you don't have any condition to stop if the game comes to a win. 

If you can comment your code to explain what it's supposed to do, I might be able to give you more.

Comment: Thanks @RichardSt-Cyr, I made the change you suggested, but unfortunately, the result is the same. However, I commented out my code and updated it on the same link. Here it is just in case you missed it above: http://ideone.com/6791d4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check up on the variations found not just the scores. Are you finding just any winning variation, or the one where the opponent plays best?

e.g. Modify your min/max Eval code to also add the move chosen to an array.

BTW it may be easier to see what is happening if you combine the min/max Eval routines into one.

WARNING UNTESTED CODE

```
int minmaxEval(int board[9], int player, int moves[9], int move) {
    if (checkDraw(board)) {
        return 0;
    }
    int finalScore = player * -1000;
    if (checkWin(board)) {
        return finalScore;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (board[i] == 0) {
            board[i] = player;
            int score = minmaxEval(board, -player, moves, move+1);
            if ( (player > 0 && score > finalScore) ||
                (player < 0 && score < finalScore) ) {
                  finalScore = score;
                  moves[move] = i;
            }
            board[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return finalScore;
}
```

If you print out moves[] in your toplevel routine you should see the variation which gave that score. A mismatch there will inform your understanding of the algorithm e.g. is it stopping when it finds a win.

In general it is important to have a way to double check your code is doing what you expect. Look into unit testing and test-driven development.

Comment: My min and max functions don't find the winning move, but rather just tell you whether the position is lost or won and the position returned isn't a winning variation at all, it seems completely random and is most definitely losing. I will definitely try to implement your suggestions on combining min and max to one method and also test out the moves in an array. I will get back to this thread and tell you what happens. Thanks a lot for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your insights, I solved the problem. There was a bug in the playMove function, where I mismatched maxEval and minEval, this causing the AI to not play for a win or draw. So, the corrected code is:

```
void playMove(int board[9], int player) {
    int finalScore = player * -1000;
    int position;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (board[i] == 0) {
            board[i] = player;
            int score;
            if (player == 1) {
                score = minEval(board);  //Previously Mismatched
            }
            else {
                score = maxEval(board);  //Previously Mismatched
            }
            if (player == 1 && score >= finalScore) {
                finalScore = score;
                position = i;
            }
            else if (player == -1 && score <= finalScore) {
                finalScore = score;
                position = i;
            }
            board[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    board[position] = player;
}
```